# rails cant find gems even after bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I am creating an application with rails, but when I run `rake db:migrate` I get the error

> Could not find coffee-script-source-1.12.2 in any of the sources
>   Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

I ran bundle install and nothing happens. When I install the gem manually through `gem install` and run `rake db:migrate` I get the same error for a different gem.

I suppose my application or bundler can't find the path to the gems `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/[gemname]`. Why is that happening? How can I install all gems at once?

EDIT: BUNDLE INSTALL output

```
Using rake 12.3.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 0.9.1
Using json 1.8.6
Using minitest 5.11.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.4
Using activesupport 4.2.6
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
Using nokogiri 1.8.1
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.9
Using crass 1.0.3
Using loofah 2.1.1
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using actionview 4.2.6
Using rack 1.6.8
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.6
Using globalid 0.4.1
Using activejob 4.2.6
Using mini_mime 1.0.0
Using mail 2.7.0
Using actionmailer 4.2.6
Using activemodel 4.2.6
Using arel 6.0.4
Using activerecord 4.2.6
Using activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter 1.6.9
Using debug_inspector 0.0.3
Using binding_of_caller 0.8.0
Using bundler 1.16.1
Using byebug 9.1.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.20.0
Using railties 4.2.6
Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
Using ffi 1.9.18
Using multi_json 1.13.1
Using jbuilder 2.7.0
Using jquery-rails 4.3.1
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Using rails 4.2.6
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.2
Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
Using rdoc 4.3.0
Using ruby-oci8 2.2.5.1
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using sass 3.5.5
Using tilt 2.0.8
Using sass-rails 5.0.7
Using sdoc 0.4.2
Using spring 2.0.2
Using turbolinks-source 5.1.0
Using turbolinks 5.1.0
Using uglifier 4.1.3
Using web-console 2.3.0
Bundle complete! 13 Gemfile dependencies, 61 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Comment: the first line of your `Gemfile` should be where you source your gems.  What does this line say?  It should say something of the sort:  `source 'https://rubygems.org'`. Also, your command should be `rake db:migrate`, not `rake:db migrate`

Comment: it says that and i am running the correct command. i typed it wrong here.

Comment: "I ran bundle install and nothing happens." what do you mean by "nothing happens"? can you show us the output of `bundle install`?

Comment: @TamerShlash updated my question with the output

Comment: Could you also post your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: Do you run it with `bundle exec rake db:migrate` or just `rake db:migrate`? Since installing gem manually solves issue for one gem, I believe you don't execute command using bundled gems...